# Crash when received One Signal nofication on Android Target S+

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-messaging, onesignal

i'm using OneSignal for push notification on Android . but when i change the Android target Sdk to 31 it crash when receive notification

My Android Manifest :
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9jSGd.png

My error :
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lgf9A.png

Answer (score 0):

This likely comes coming from a `PendingIntent`, which doesn't have the correct flags set.

Comment: yes , but this PendingIntent from com.onesignal.GcmBroadcastReceiver

Comment: https://github.com/OneSignal/react-native-onesignal/issues/1310 i found a solution from here , i update the implement OneSignal to 4.3.6 and it fixed